# Hover over a button: Display link?

Tags: html, css

You know how when you hover over a normal link, your browser displays the url on the bottom of the screen?  Is there a way to do that while hovering over a button link?

```
<button class="myButtonClass" onclick="location.href='mylink.php'">here goes text</button>

<style>
  .myButtonClass {
  height:80px;
  width:340px;
  padding: 0;
border: none;
   background-image:url('button.png');
   background-color:#FFFFFF;
  }

  .myButtonClass:hover
{
background-color:#cccccc;
???????????make link appear on bottom?????????
} 

</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use anchor tag instead of button? Then style your a to look like a button

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is called window.status.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.status

so, you could code it like this

```
window.status = "Change this..."
```

Note: This status bar isn't changeable most of the time and is disabled in browser by default in most browsers.

And as I said before, another solution you could do is:

- Why not just use anchor tag instead of button? Then style your a to look like a button

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to create a URL image (the image would look like a button) like so:

```
<a src='location.href="mylink.php"' title='Delete'><img src='button.jpg'></a>
```

But then you'd have to create some events so it changes appearance when it's being clicked or held down.

The easiest way to show the URL would be to add a title.

```
<button class="myButtonClass" onclick="location.href='mylink.php'" title="location.href='mylink.php'">here goes text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `title` attribute is OK but you can't style it easily. Instead you can try using `:before` pseudo-element to render the popup like this:

```
.myButtonClass {
  height:80px;
  width:340px;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background-image:url(button.png);
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  position:relative; 
}

.myButtonClass:hover {
  background-color:#cccccc;
}
.myButtonClass:hover:before {
  content:attr(data-src);        
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<button class="myButtonClass" data-src="mylink.php">here goes text</button>
```

**JS**:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.myButtonClass');
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
    location.href = this.getAttribute('data-src');
};
```

It's better not to use inline event property to register some handlers, the code is even much cleaner if you use jQuery:

```
$('.myButtonClass').click(function(){
    location.href = $(this).attr('data-src');
 });
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/c6Ry4/2/)